# Navigating through completion possibilities with icomplete-vertical

Tags: icomplete

I am enabling `icomplete-vertical` and having difficulties about how to use it.

With the standard `icomplete`, I get the list of possible completions in the minibuffer and can navigate between the different completions with `C-,` and `C-.`

What is the procedure to navigate the completion possibilities with `icomplete-vertical`?

Answer (score 0):

See `C-h v icomplete-vertical-mode-minibuffer-map RET`:

```lisp
(defvar icomplete-vertical-mode-minibuffer-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map (kbd "C-n")    #'icomplete-forward-completions)
    (define-key map (kbd "C-p")    #'icomplete-backward-completions)
    (define-key map (kbd "<down>") #'icomplete-forward-completions)
    (define-key map (kbd "<up>")   #'icomplete-backward-completions)
    (define-key map (kbd "M-<")    #'icomplete-vertical-goto-first)
    (define-key map (kbd "M->")    #'icomplete-vertical-goto-last)
    map)
  "Keymap used by `icomplete-vertical-mode' in the minibuffer.")
```

So, by default, either <kbd>C-n</kbd> and <kbd>C-p</kbd> or <kbd><down></kbd> and <kbd><up></kbd>.

Comment: I cannot see `icomplete-vertical-mode-minibuffer-map`.  I am using Version 0.3

Comment: I think that there is `icomplete-vertical-mode` in Emacs 28.  I am using Emacs 27.2